# How to change a macro into a function in c++

Tags: c++, function

How can I declare a unknown type parameter(eg: dynamic parameter type) in a function while converting the Macro into function.

Declared Macro**

```
 #define FOO(x) static_cast<void>(x)
```

**Example:**

1.`FOO("String")`

2.`FOO(25)`

3.`FOO((20*1)-3.14)`

Comment: `template<class T> void FOO(T const&) {}` ?

Comment: @fabian, the above suggestion gives an error -  "invalid use of void expression"

Comment: @DHARANIKANNA and use of the macro doesn't trigger a compiler error?? Show a [mcve] as required here please!

Comment: What are you *trying* to do in your code? Casting to `void` is mostly useful to get rid of compiler warnings about unused results/variables, and to make a dummy macro that might do something in other cases, the latter of which *seems* to be the case here. Your macro is a cast to `void`, and the function provided in the comment has a return type of `void`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Actually I have Facing Mishra warning for declaring the macro, So trying to change the macro into a function.

Comment: @DHARANIKANNA you probably meant _**Misra** warning_. Again: Can you please [edit] your question, and show how that macro is actually used. There's not much sense to have something like that, no matter, if it's enclosed in a macro or function.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Actually I face a Misra warning for Declaring macro in my code, But I have suppressed it using "PRQA" Even it was not suppressing. That's why I have trying to convert the macro into function.